# Best Results For Asking Questions

Tags: support, reputation, questions, responses

I usually only want to ask questions.  I want to get the best results on my questions, is there anything I can do to ensure this?

Would I get better results from asking questions if I had more reputation?

Does responsiveness help?  I seem to get better/more responses when I am more responsive.

Comment: What would qualify as "best results" for you? One clear answer? Ten answers but only half bearing any relation to what you asked?  200 lines of code when you say "I don't know where to start"?

Comment: @PolyGeo Out of those choices, one clear one.  But the more answers the more likely to be a correct answer.  And sometimes it's more about a lot of responses since there is not only 1 right answer.

Comment: How can I delete this question, all I can do is vote to delete it.  I now have only 1 rep.

Comment: You cannot delete this question because it has an upvoted answer - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/215590

Answer (score 7):

If you want good answers, you need to ask good questions

Good questions are detailed (enough), organised (so someone who dosen't have the same environment you have can walk through it before going down the rabbit hole), and specific.

I also (personally) find that *hard* questions attract the best answers simply cause folks with good skills gravitate towards the challenge.

As many people often use tags or the front page to find things to answer, *appropriate* tags - don't throw 20 tags on it, but make sure your tags reflect the question help. Your title should be clear - If someone sees a title that makes less sense, its not going to stand out.

*Responsiveness* is good. However, that also indicates there's missing information that needs to be filled in. It does mean though, at this point, at least one user is engaged with question and is likely to follow through.

I don't think reputation is a factor - many high reputation users answer much more than they ask. *Some* users report they look at accept rates so - if an answer helps, make sure you do what's necessary (upvote? Select as correct?)